# Full text search on multiple joined tables

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, join

I'm trying to set up a full text search in PostgreSQL but coming across the problem that the more tables I join to the query the fewer the results I get back.

The tables I am trying to join are:

- article
- keyword
- author
- organisation

There is a many-to-many relationship between `article` and all the other tables.

I am basing my query on that found [here](http://blog.lostpropertyhq.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) and at a loss as to why it's failing. The query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT title
FROM (
  SELECT article_title AS title, 
  to_tsvector(article.article_title) ||
  to_tsvector(string_agg(keyword.keyword, '')) ||
  to_tsvector(string_agg(organisation.org_name, '')) ||
  to_tsvector(string_agg(author.name, ''))
  AS document
  FROM article
  JOIN article_keywords on article.id = article_keywords.article_id
  JOIN keyword on keyword.id = article_keywords.keyword_id
  JOIN article_authors on article.id = article_authors.article_id
  JOIN author on author.id = article_authors.author_id
  JOIN article_organisations on article.id = article_organisations.article_id
  JOIN organisation on organisation.id = article_organisations.organisation_id
  GROUP BY article.article_title) AS p_search
WHERE p_search.document @@ to_tsquery('David & Feeney');
```

In the example above, I want to search across all tables for mentions of 'David Feeney'. There are two entries in the author table for him but so far none are returned.

Comment: The `string_agg` with empty string delimiter looks suspicious. What's the point of producing `Author1Author2Author3` ?

Comment: Your version of Postgres should *always* be declared.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm working in version 9.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The blog post you refer to](http://blog.lostpropertyhq.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) is ***wrong*** in using `[INNER] JOIN` between `post` and `posts_tags`. Nothing enforces that at least one tag exists, so posts without tags are excluded from the result.
(Also, why is there no PK for `posts_tags`? A dubious DB design.)

You copied that error and made it much worse by combining multiple relationships that way. Each many-to-many relationship allows for the possibility of **no (zero) related rows**. If you join multiple tables that way, only such rows from `article` remain that have relatives in each and every of the joined tables.

On the other hand, you **multiply** rows with multiple relatives in multiple tables, resulting in a potentially ***huge*** intermediary table with lots and lots of redundant copies in the aggregated result. Detailed explanation:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)

This query should work with Postgres 9.1 or later:

```
SELECT a.article_title AS title
FROM   article a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT x.article_id AS id, string_agg(y.keyword, ' ') AS txt
   FROM   article_keywords x
   JOIN   keyword          y ON y.id = x.keyword_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) k USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT x.article_id AS id, string_agg(y.name, ' ') AS txt
   FROM   article_authors x
   JOIN   author          y ON y.id = x.author_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT x.article_id AS id, string_agg(y.org_name, ' ') AS txt
   FROM   article_organisations x
   JOIN   organisation          y ON y.id = x.organisation_id
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) o USING (id)
WHERE  to_tsvector(concat_ws(' ', a.article_title, k.txt, a.txt, o.txt))
    @@ to_tsquery('David & Feeney');
```

Using [**`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) we don't exclude rows without relatives in the joined tables.

By aggregating multiple rows before joining we avoid the cross-multiplication of rows.

I concatenate the string with [`concat_ws()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (which ignores potential NULL values from any of the contributing sources) and call `to_tsvector()` only once, which should be a bit cheaper.

Besides ***correctly*** aggregating input from all related tables, this should also be among the ***fastest possible*** solutions. Aggregate first, join later.

That is - as long as you want to ***combine*** all words to search for `David & Feeney`. For instance, this way you get a match for an article associated with any organization that has the word 'Feeney' in its name and any author with 'David' in his / her name. That's what your query suggests. It's typically *not* what you'd want, though.

I would *not* concatenate everything for this purpose, but rather search in each table separately for the *combination* of both words ...

Also adding separators between word to avoid false positives from matching illegally combined words, like [@Daniel hinted in his comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107801/postgresql-full-text-search-on-multiple-tables/107962#comment196366_107801).

And I remove the subquery that's not needed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've changed tack a little now and think maybe just searching across title and keyword columns may yield better results, while also returning people and organisations for further filtering on the front end. To that end I found another [blog](https://blog.lateral.io/2015/05/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql/) using a different method. I've implemented across my two columns in the keyword and article tables but struggling to create the query to search across both. Any suggestions? Or is this a for another questions?

Comment: @sammy88888888: Yes, best put the new question into a new question. You can always link to this one for context.

Comment: New question posted [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108005/full-text-search-on-two-tsvector-columns). Thanks for the above. I got it working but it took around 8 seconds to process which is too slow. I'm hoping this new method will be quicker! I'll mark the above as correct though :)